# Prove that $ n\ge\max(k,m)\implies k\,m/n\ge1-\prod_{0\le j<k}(1-m/(n-j))$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

A bag contains $m$ marked balls among $n$. We randomly pick and remove $k$ balls. The probability $p$ that we picked at least one marked ball is
$$p=1-\prod_{0\le j<k}\left(1-\frac m{n-j}\right)$$
How can we prove $p\displaystyle\le\frac{k\,m}n$ ?

Motivating [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/80436/555) is about probability of intrusion after $k$ attempts in a system with $m$ valid random tokens among $n$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: thanks for massaging the title per relevant [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles). I made further changes towards this.

Comment: Hint: What is the probability of the event that you picked up a particular marked ball? Then try writing the given event as the union of $k$ events and use the union bound to conclude the result.

Comment: @sudeep5221: the probability of picking up a particular marked ball is $\displaystyle q=1-\prod_{0\le j<k}\left(1-\frac1{n-j}\right)$. By the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality), $p\le m\,q$. That would allows to conclude if I could prove $q\le k/n$. Which does hold. I'll manage to get it..

Comment: I can't quite follow how you evaluated the probability of picking up a particular marked ball. It is just $\binom{n-1}{k-1}/\binom{n}{k} = \frac{k}{n}$. Applying the union bound gives the answer. Maybe the expression you wrote does evaluate to $k/n$ but I think evaluating this way might be easier.

Comment: @sudeep5221: My formula for $q$ indeed simplifies to $k/n$ just as you suggest, I just need to find how, or understand yours... Thanks so much! I evaluated the probability of picking a particular ball in the $k$ picks as the complement of the probability of not picking it in the $k$ picks, which is the product of the probabilities of not picking it at each of the $k$ picks numbered $0\ldots j-1$, and that later probability is the complement of the probability of picking that ball assuming it was not picked in earlier picks, which is 1 in $n-j$ since $n-j$ balls remain at pick $j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof follows the hint in [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7517965?noredirect=1).

The probability of picking up a particular marked ball at pick $j$ is $1/n$, irrespective of $j$ (for the same reason that the order in picking straws is immaterial to the probability one has to pick the shortest straw). Since these $k$ events are exclusive, the probability $q$ of picking up a particular marked ball in $k$ picks is $k/n$.

By the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality), the probability $p$ of picking any $m$ marked ball verifies $p\le m\,q$.

$p\displaystyle\le\frac{k\,m}n$ follows.